# Implementation of hreflang in sitemap for different TLD

Tags: localization, internationalization, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

I'm implementing targeting our multilingual webpage for users in different countries using hreflang in sitemap.xml. I have read google tutorial but it didn't solve my problem. Our webpage has different TLD for each language.

Let's say we have two TLD: `www.example.cz` for czech users, `www.example.de` for german users.

In my sitemap xml for czech mutation (`www.example.cz/sitemap.xml`) I have:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.cz</loc>
        <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="de"
            href="http://www.example.de"
            />
        <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="cs"
            href="http://www.example.cz"
            />
    </url> 

    <url> 
    ...other www.example.cz/* url and so on...
    </url> 

</urlset>
```

I have also sitemap for `www.example.de` (`www.example.de/sitemap.xml`) like:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>http://www.example.de</loc>
        <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="de"
            href="http://www.example.de"
            />
        <xhtml:link
            rel="alternate"
            hreflang="cs"
            href="http://www.example.cz"
            />
    </url> 

    <url> 
    ...other www.example.de/* url and so on...
    </url> 

</urlset>
```

Is it ok? Google Webmaster Tools complains that there are "no return tags". Should I add `<loc>http://www.example.de</loc>` to my `www.example.cz/sitemap.xml`? I think it would be wrong because `www.example.de` has its own sitemap.xml with regarding urls defined.

Comment: After few weeks without changing sitemaps configuration, Google Webmaster Tools descreased the number of errors called "no return tags". Maybe there is a problem on the crawler site. Anyway any other experience from you would be nice...

Comment: I'm in your same situation but I put the hreflang tag directly on every page inside <head> tag and for each TLD I create a "classic" sitemap (without reference to hreflang). This seems to work too.